# OAUTH2 - Replace resource server HttpSecurity with Preauthorize

Tags: java, spring, oauth-2.0

I have a spring auth2 server and it works for logged in users (Bearer token in the request). I want to allow anonymous users (Users that aren't logged in so no Bearer token) to view certain data.

In my resource server I have this configuration

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  http
    .anonymous()
      .and()
    .authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
      .and()
    .exceptionHandling()
      .accessDeniedHandler(new OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler());
}
```

As you can see, I have http.anonymous().and() at the beginning and yet when I call a rest end point without a bearer token I get an unauthorized exception. Can anybody explain this to me??

Comment: I used in my projects something like this `.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/pontoatendimento/*","/up").permitAll()` where "pontoatendimento" and "up" are endpoints without security...

Comment: The `permitAll` doesn't solve your problem?

Comment: The thing is, I have a lot of urls (More than 50). And instead of putting them all in here I want to use the Preauthorize annotation. Instead of allowing anonymous I could also disable the security here and leave it to the PreAuthorize annotation. How can I do that?